# Java 8 Stream Collecting Set

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

To better understand the new stream API I'm trying to convert some old code, but I'm stuck on this one.

```
 public Collection<? extends File> asDestSet() {
    HashMap<IFileSourceInfo, Set<File>> map = new HashMap<IFileSourceInfo, Set<File>>();
    //...
    Set<File> result = new HashSet<File>();
    for (Set<File> v : map.values()) {
        result.addAll(v);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can't seem to create a valid Collector for it:

```
 public Collection<? extends File> asDestSet() {
    HashMap<IFileSourceInfo, Set<File>> map = new HashMap<IFileSourceInfo, Set<File>>();
    //...
    return map.values().stream().collect(/* what? */);
}
```

Comment: `return map.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());` or `.collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));` as there is no guarantee behind the set implementation returned by `toSet()`.

Comment: or `.collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll)`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
return map.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The `flatMap` flattens all of your sets into single stream.