# Stream<Map<String,String>> to Set<String> values in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of Map how can i get Set having values of Map?

here i what i've done partially

```
Set<String> jcfTargetTables = measure.getConditionMap().values()
        .stream()
        .map(Condition::getJoinConditionFilter)
        .filter(jcf -> jcf!=null)
        .map(JoinConditionFilter::getTableMapping);
```

the last line gives me a `Stream<Map<String,String>>`, how do i proceed to get Set that is values of Map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Stream Collecting Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464953/java-8-stream-collecting-set)

Comment: Is your intention to have a set of all values from all maps in the stream? or to have a set of values per map?

Comment: @Ernest Kiwele set of all the values from all the maps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have maps in your last mapping, then all that's left is transform it to a stream of values in those maps, then collect them as a set:

```
Set<String> jcfTargetTables = measure.getConditionMap().values()
    .stream()
    .map(Condition::getJoinConditionFilter)
    .filter(jcf -> jcf!=null)
    .map(JoinConditionFilter::getTableMapping)
    .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if all the steps you currently have are necessary, but building on what you have, you can use `flatMap` to get a `Stream` of all the values:

```
Set<String> jcfTargetTables = measure.getConditionMap().values()
    .stream()
    .map(Condition::getJoinConditionFilter)
    .filter(jcf -> jcf!=null)
    .map(JoinConditionFilter::getTableMapping)
    .flatMap(m->m.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```